# IIS8 and URL redirect using URL Rewrite Module

Tags: url, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have two sites running on a Server 2012 R2 web server:

- firstSite, port 80
- secondSite, port 1234

Right now, users have to type in the host name, port number, and sub folder in order to view the 'Second Site' `http://webServer:1234/subFolder`.

I'm trying to simplify the URL so that all users can just type in the URL `site.myDomain.com` and have it (permanently) redirected to `site.mydomain.com:1234/subFolder`.

I've tried applying the following rule on my secondSite:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://site.mydomain.com:1234/subFolder"  />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But doesn't seem to do anything.

A `CNAME` record has already been configured in DNS for `site.myDomain.com` to resolve to `http://webServer`.

I just need help with getting the redirection to 'secondSite' at port 1234.

Comment: I assume the first site is hosted on IIS and the rule is running within the context of the first site.  If so, it should work...to validate your setup, I'd start with this article and the augment with your use case: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Both sites are running adjacent on IIS8 on the same host.  The rule is currently running in the context of the second site which I just now realized, doesn't make any sense.  I'll move it to the first site tomorrow and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the extra pair of eyes.  It worked after moving the rule to the first site.

Comment: Happy you got it to work.  Would you mind giving my an up-vote?

Comment: I'm new, how do I do that or mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I assume the first site is hosted on IIS and the rule is running within the context of the first site. If so, it should work...to validate your setup, I'd start with this article and the augment with your use case:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score -1):

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
         <add wildcard="/some/folder/path/" destination="/new/folder/" />
      </httpRedirect>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```